# Neo4j 3D graph node placement issue

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am using JavaScript to bind Neo4J 3D-graph to HTML, my search query have multiple nodes, when displaying the nodes are scattering across the page, first will display at the center and later moving out.  Please help me to how to place all nodes at the center.

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?